# How update SQL Server table from datagridview using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I want update a SQL Server table from datagridview.

1. In my SQL Server table, I have columns `no varchar(255)` and `golongan varchar(255)`
2. And in the datagridview I have nip and gol

[image]

I want to update `golongan` with values `gol` from datagridview.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example

1.Create a new Windows Forms application.
[image]

2.Create a database (named Sample). Add a table tbl_Record. The following is the table schema for creating tbl_Record.

[image]

3.Create a form (named frmMain) and drop a Label, TextBox, Button and DataGridView control from the ToolBox.

[image]

Now, go to the frmMain.cs code and add the System.Data and System.Data.SqlClient namespaces.

**frmMain.cs Code**

```
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace InsertUpdateDeleteDemo  
{  
    public partial class frmMain : Form  
    {  
        SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");  
        SqlCommand cmd;  
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;  
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
        int ID = 0;  
        public frmMain()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            DisplayData();  
        }  
        //Insert Data  
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (txt_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_Record(Name,State) values(@name,@state)", con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                con.Close();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");  
            }  
        }  
        //Display Data in DataGridView  
        private void DisplayData()  
        {  
            con.Open();  
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();  
            adapt=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Record",con);  
            adapt.Fill(dt);  
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
            con.Close();  
        }  
        //Clear Data  
        private void ClearData()  
        {  
            txt_Name.Text = "";  
            txt_State.Text = "";  
            ID = 0;  
        }  
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event  
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)  
        {  
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());  
            txt_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();  
            txt_State.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();  
        }  
        //Update Record  
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (txt_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Record set Name=@name,State=@state where ID=@id", con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");  
                con.Close();  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");  
            }  
        }  
        //Delete Record  
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if(ID!=0)  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tbl_Record where ID=@id",con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",ID);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                con.Close();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

In the preceding code, I created a dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick Event for updating and deleting the selected record. When the user clicks on the Row Header of a row then the data present in the cell of the row is stored into the TextBoxes. The DisplayData() method fills in the data in the DataGridView.

The Clear() method clears the data present in the TextBox as well as in the ID(int) variable.

**Final Preview**

[image]